# NPE hard to spot from the logcat it seems to be the Arraylist but each item should be set

Tags: java, android, retrofit

GitHub Repo app building for learning purposes I've become stuck in this world of NullPointerException.

So it says on line 119 the ArrayList is null it's a simple Callback via Retrofit
where I try to get the data and then set they data further on. I'm unsure of where exactly in the process it fails as it just points to the initialization of the array on line 119 but I'm iterating over that array and then adding each item to a collection.

Someone with more knowhow would be able to spot something that I can't.

Any advice welcome.

```
Call<GitHubRepo> call = gitHubClient.getRepos(searchTerm, pageNumber, resultsPerPage);
call.enqueue(new Callback<GitHubRepo>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<GitHubRepo> call, Response<GitHubRepo> response) {
        ArrayList<Item> itemsList = response.body().getItems();
        for(int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
            ModelCachedGitHubProject currentProject = new ModelCachedGitHubProject();
            Item responseItem = itemsList.get(i);
            currentProject.setOwnerName(responseItem.getOwner().getLogin());
            currentProject.setRepoName(responseItem.getName());
            currentProject.setRepoSize(responseItem.getSize());
            currentProject.setHasWiki(responseItem.isHas_wiki());
            currentProject.setCreatedAt(responseItem.getCreated_at());
            currentProject.setPushedAt(responseItem.getPushed_at());
            currentProject.setUpdatedAt(responseItem.getUpdated_at());
            currentProject.setHtmlUrl(responseItem.getHtml_url());
            currentProject.setAvatarUrl(responseItem.getOwner().getAvatar_url());
            currentProject.setLanguage(responseItem.getLanguage());
            currentProject.setForksCount(responseItem.getForks_count());
            currentProject.setScore(responseItem.getScore());
            currentProject.setDescription(responseItem.getDescription());
            gitHubProjectsList.add(currentProject);
        }
```

Any other classes that are needed just ask. Thanks.

StackTrace :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.benmohammad.repoapp, PID: 2325
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.benmohammad.repoapp.data.webservice.apiresponse.GitHubRepo.getItems()' on a null object reference
        at com.benmohammad.repoapp.data.DataRepository$1.onResponse(DataRepository.java:119)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda
```

GitHub Repo [Repo](https://github.com/BenMohammad/RepoApp)

Thanks

```
public void updateFromWebservice(final String searchTerm, final int pageNumber, int resultsPerPage) {
        webServiceMessageCallStatus.setValue(WebServiceMessage.UPDATING_STATUS);
        final List<ModelCachedGitHubProject> gitHubProjectsList =  new ArrayList<>();
        if(retrofit == null || gitHubClient == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(GitHubClientService.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            gitHubClient = retrofit.create(GitHubClientService.class);
        }
        Call<GitHubRepo> call = gitHubClient.getRepos(searchTerm, pageNumber, resultsPerPage);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GitHubRepo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GitHubRepo> call, Response<GitHubRepo> response) {
                ArrayList<Item> itemsList = response.body().getItems();
                for(int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
                    ModelCachedGitHubProject currentProject = new ModelCachedGitHubProject();
                    Item responseItem = itemsList.get(i);
                    currentProject.setOwnerName(responseItem.getOwner().getLogin());
                    currentProject.setRepoName(responseItem.getName());
                    currentProject.setRepoSize(responseItem.getSize());
                    currentProject.setHasWiki(responseItem.isHas_wiki());
                    currentProject.setCreatedAt(responseItem.getCreated_at());
                    currentProject.setPushedAt(responseItem.getPushed_at());
                    currentProject.setUpdatedAt(responseItem.getUpdated_at());
                    currentProject.setHtmlUrl(responseItem.getHtml_url());
                    currentProject.setAvatarUrl(responseItem.getOwner().getAvatar_url());
                    currentProject.setLanguage(responseItem.getLanguage());
                    currentProject.setForksCount(responseItem.getForks_count());
                    currentProject.setScore(responseItem.getScore());
                    currentProject.setDescription(responseItem.getDescription());
                    gitHubProjectsList.add(currentProject);
                }

                if(!gitHubProjectsList.isEmpty()) {
                    boolean clearPreviousCache;
                    if(pageNumber == 1) {
                        clearPreviousCache = true;
                        saveLastSearchTerm(searchTerm);

                    } else clearPreviousCache = false;
                    cacheProjectsList(gitHubProjectsList, clearPreviousCache);
                    setLastRefreshDate(new Date());
                    webServiceMessageCallStatus.postValue(WebServiceMessage.ON_RESPONSE_SUCCESS);
                } else {
                    if(pageNumber == 1)
                        webServiceMessageCallStatus.postValue(WebServiceMessage.ON_RESPONSE_NOTHING_FOUND);
                    else {
                        webServiceMessageCallStatus.postValue(WebServiceMessage.ON_RESPONSE_NO_MORE_RESULTS);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GitHubRepo> call, Throwable t) {
                webServiceMessageCallStatus.postValue(WebServiceMessage.ON_FAILURE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the Response you are sending in, my best guess response is null, assuming you are talking about ArrayList<Item> itemsList line.. We can't see line numbers.

Comment: Your response body is null. Can you share the raw response you get when hitting the api?

Comment: oemel09 how do you mean?How will I get the raw response .......?

Comment: E. g. through debugging and examining your response object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response is null, assuming you are talking about ArrayList itemsList line.. We can't see line numbers. If you look at the stack trace, it says `.getItems()' on a null object reference.` That means `response.getBody()` is null. So you need to check where that response is being initialized (being sent) and make sure there isn't a problem in that class/service.

Comment: it seems app kept crashing but after changing https to http I dont seem to get the crash just need to work on other things but i will accept your answer.